# How to pick up true or false from function

Tags: php, pdo, user-registration

I am currently writing a isRegistered function. This function is written within a class called User. This is the code:

```
public function isRegistered($email){
        $ir =   $this->db->prepare('select * from users where email=?');
        $ir->bindParam(1, $email);
        $ir->execute();
        if ($ir->rowCount()==1){
            return true;
        }
        else { return false;}
}//end of function isRegistered
```

I am instantiating the class and this function on the register page, and I am trying to do this:

```
    if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
        $email  =   $_POST['email'];
        $fp =   new User();
        $fp->isRegistered($email);
        if($fp==1){
        echo "email exists";    
        }
        else {echo "email doesn't exist.";}
    }
    else echo "Please enter an email address.";
```

Obviously this is not working. How do I get it to work? What is the right way to do it?
I know I am returning either a true or a false from the method `isRegistered`. I just don't know how to pick that response up when I instantiate it.

Comment: You are returning `true` or `false`, but testing whether it's `1`. You should test against the value you are expecting. Or simply test `if($fp)`

Comment: You can simplify the return statements: `return $ir->rowCount()==1`.

Comment: return $ir->rowCount()==1 what does this return? True or false? Or 1 or 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
if($fp->isRegistered($email)){
   ...
```

Or assign the return value of your function to `$fp`...